# Moving from scriptalicious to jquery, show/hide effect on link in asp.net repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In my blog, I have a repeater, containing the actual blog and the comments to that blog. I use a show/hide effect on the comments with Scriptalicious now. But now I want to change it to Jquery. But I'm having some troubles. It seems like i have to declear a jquery script for each div that is going to have this effect?

This is the html where the link for showing/hiding the comments is today (with scriptalicious):

```
<a href="#" onclick="new Effect.Appear('i<%# Eval("id") %>', {duration: 1});return false;">Show comments (<%# CountComments (DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id")) %>)</a> | <a href="#" onclick="new Effect.Fade('i<%# Eval("id") %>', {duration: 0.5});return false;">Hide comments</a>
```

As you can see, I'm using: `onclick="new Effect.Fade('i<%# Eval("id") %>'` the new Effect.Fade, passing in the id.
Could someone please give me a hint on how I can do this with Jquery?

**UPDATE**
Now it's working. I used the code from the accepted answer, and did some small adjustments. The link I use now looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="i<%# Eval("id") %>">Vis kommentarer (<%# CountComments (DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id")) %>)</a>
```

And there is a div that contains the comments, looks like this:

```
<div id="i<%# Eval("id") %>" style="display: none;"><%# GetComments (DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id")) %></div>
```

And the Jquery function to do the magic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a:contains('Vis kommentarer')").click(function () {
        $id = $(this).attr('title');
        $('#' + $id + '').show();
        return false;
    })
});
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$("a:contains('Show comments')").click(function() {
  $id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#' + id + '').show();
});
```

Comment: Yes, but how do i pass the id of the clicked link to this function? How do i make the call in the link?

Comment: Thank you! I will try this in a few hours, and give feedback/accept.

Comment: It worked, with some small adjustments. Thank you very much for your help. I will edit my question to add the code that i used to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

How about a function?

```
<a href="#" onclick="show(this,'i<%# Eval("id") %>');">Show comments (<%# CountComments (DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id")) %>)</a> | <a href="#" onclick="show(this,'i<%# Eval("id") %>');">Hide comments</a>  
  function show(this, val)
    {
        new Effect.Fade(val, {duration: 0.5});return false;
    }
```

Comment: This is not working. I want to move it to a function like:  $(document).ready(function () {....

Comment: Do you want it for all links? And how are you going to pass parameters?

Comment: Yes, and your question is part of what i'm struggeling finding out :)

Comment: Well you can but that would be a little "hacky", why not stick with this simple function?